# Call built-in function if overwritten by a variable of the same name

Tags: python

I have a variable `type`and I want to use builtin `type()` function

Example

```
def fun(inv):
   log.debug('type of inv {}'.format(type(inv)))
   type = 'int'
```

I get the following error when i run the function:

```
AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'type'
```

Comment: Why not rename your variable?

Answer (score 16):

Your `type` variable has overwritten* the built-in `type` function. But you can still access the original via the `__builtin__` module in Python 2, or `builtins` in Python 3.

Python 2:

```
>>> type = "string"
>>> type("test")
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: 'str' object is not callable
>>> import __builtin__
>>> __builtin__.type("test")
<type 'str'>
```

Python 3:

```
>>> type = "string"
>>> type("test")
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: 'str' object is not callable
>>> import builtins
>>> builtins.type("test")
<type 'str'>
```

However, it would be better to avoid the need for this by choosing a different variable name.

It's also worth mentioning that it makes no difference that you only assign to `type` after attempting to call `type` as a function. In Python, a name is bound to a function as a local variable if it is assigned to *anywhere* within that function (and is not declared global). So even though you only assign to `type` in the second line of the function, `type` is still a local variable throughout the whole function.

* Strictly speaking, "hidden" would probably be a better description, as the built-in `type` function is still there, it's just that [Python resolves variables names looking for local definition first, and built-ins last](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/291978/short-description-of-the-scoping-rules).

Comment: While I agree that function names shouldn't be retasked as variable names, I can't stand that Python a) allows it, and b) claims so many incredibly common terms as function names. It's wrong to expect Python users to know every single built-in function name and not to use terms like "type" and "range". :(

Comment: Code in the standard Python library does it, e.g. functions in the `tempfile` module have a `dir` parameter, meaning that `dir` inside those function is usually not the normal `dir()` and this messes up syntax highlighting in the function calls. https://docs.python.org/3/library/tempfile.html

Answer (score 1):

If you assign a value to a variable inside a function, it becomes a local variable in that function. It will no longer refer to it's original global built-in function, even though you assign a new value at the end of the function.

You must be getting this error too.

```
UnboundLocalError: local variable 'type' referenced before assignment
```

Best practice is not to override builtin functions or modules.

Answer (score 1):

It is not a good practice to use builtin functions as variable name. So You can rename your variable name from **type** to **_type**